# Recovering from UART Disconnection

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I'm working on my second project using [RXTX](http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java), and there were a few things I left unresolved in the last project (like error handling) that I'm trying to fix in this one.

One of them is recovering from a UART disconnection, which seems to happen after a computer sleep or when you pull the plug of an RS-232 USB interface.

This is the error I get:

```
Error 0x5 at ..\rxtx\src\termios.c(517): Access is denied.
Error 0x5 at ..\rxtx\src\termios.c(2712): Access is denied.
Error 0x5 at ..\rxtx\src\termios.c(2601): Access is denied.
Error 0x5 at ..\rxtx\src\termios.c(1490): Access is denied.
Error 0x5 at ..\rxtx\src\termios.c(1301): Access is denied.
```

**[Here](http://marc.info/?l=rxtx&m=125308516701890&w=2), Ilkka Myller proposes a nice fix but it looks it was never implemented - was it?**

> "We could implement a method to detect lost UART in event loop at
>   native lib side and introduce a new Java side SerialPortEvent type
>   UART_DISCONNECT. The native lib would send that event in case of error
>   and proceed to automatically close the serial port and clear the
>   invalid handles etc. (reset to fault free state)."

**In case it wasn't, does any other lib handle such disconnections?**